# iOS RXSwift how to get value from .success Result?

Tags: swift3, ios11, rx-swift, associated-types

**What is the correct syntax to get a value associated with .success Result in RXSwift?**

```
.map{ (result : Result<Double>) -> Double in
        //how to get duration from result? this does not work
        let duration : Double = result.success.value
        return duration
}
```

Comment: What type is `Result` ? I'm guessing it is an enum and you need to use a switch statement.

Answer (score 2):

Adding a generic extension:

```
enum Result<T> {
    case success(T)
    case failure(Error)
}

extension Result {

    var successResult: T? {
        guard case let .success(value) = self else { return nil }
        return value
    }
}
```

With the above you can do:

```
result.successResult.map { duration in 
    // do something with duration
}
```

Comment: @AlexStone added the method as an extension. I wouldn't bother unless it's in a library that can't be edited. Frankly, I would expect any decent `Result` library to already have a method like this as well as one to extract the error, and a map and flatMap too.

Answer (score 0):

Result in Swift has a get() function that returns the success value as a throwing expression. So you can call something like:

```
var successVal = try? result.get()
```